# How to show immediate changes in a TableView in JavaFx?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to make a tableview in javafx that it can show me the added row in a real time, my goal is to write a program that it can import the row in a table view one by one, I tried the code below:

```
 public class Controller implements Initializable {


@FXML
private TableView<Logs> table;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Logs, Integer> numCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Logs, Integer> nameCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Logs, String> familyCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Logs, String> JobCol;

private int num = 1;
private List<Logs> listLogs = new ArrayList();
private ObservableList<Logs> observableListlogs;

public Controller() {
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
   numCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Logs, Integer>("num"));
    nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Logs, Integer>("name"));
    familyCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Logs, String>("family"));
   jobCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Logs, String>("job"));

    observableListlogs = FXCollections.observableArrayList(listLogs);

    table.setItems(observableListlogs);

}

@FXML
private void captureEvents() {


    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
            "cmd.exe", "/c", "cd \"C:\\Users\\a\\Desktop\\users\"&& user.exe");
    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);

    try {
        Process p = builder.start();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line ;
        int lineNumber=1;
        while (true ) {

            line = r.readLine();

            if (line==null)
                    break;
            parseLine(line);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private void parseLine(String line) {


    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<name>(.*?)</name><family>(.*?)</family><Job>(.*?)</Job>
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("<exceed>(.*?)</exceed>");

    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);

    Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(line);
    if (m.find()) {

        try {


                Logs log = new Logs(num++, m.group(1).toString(), 
                    m.group(2).toString(), m.group(3).toString());
                       observableListlogs.add(log));


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else
        if (m1.find()) {

            try{

                    Logs log = new Logs(num++, m1.group(1));
                    observableListlogs.add(log));


            }catch (Exception e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
}
```

}

But unfortunately I don't see the content of the tableView until some exception( I make it by my self that I can see the content of the tableView, the application get locked until the exception happened) happened (I mean it doesn't show me one by one when the rows added to the table, after exception happen it shows me all the content of table view suddenly, I need to show me the contents in a real time )
What should I do to make it possible to see immediate changes in a table view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you block your main-thread by doing:

```
while (true ) {
    line = r.readLine();
    if (line==null)
        break;
    parseLine(line);
}
```

the main thread(or UI-Thread) is used for rendering the UI. If you block it by some heavy computation or IO you will experience framedrops or even freeze like in your case. You need to execute your IO code on a background-thread so your main thread is free to perform UI-updates.

as a simple workaround to get things to work for now you can simply put your code into a new Thread and start it:

```
@FXML
private void captureEvents() {

    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
            "cmd.exe", "/c", "cd \"C:\\Users\\a\\Desktop\\users\"&& user.exe");
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);

        try {
            Process p = builder.start();
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line ;
            int lineNumber=1;
            while (true ) {

                line = r.readLine();

                if (line==null)
                    break;
                parseLine(line);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

this will start a new background thread, that will perform your task. You probably want to do this task as some kind of worker-thread, but as a quick solution this should fix your problem.

Comment: thanks for your prompt response could you please explain it more? or give me some example of how can I solve this problem